# How to Identify an dictionary inside an dictionary

Tags: python, python-3.x

I have a dictionary like this:

```
   test = {'user_id':125, 'company':'XXXX', 'payload': {"tranx": "456b62448367","payload": {"snr": "25%","Soil": 45,"humidity": 85}}}
```

The requirement is :

the payload inside a dictionary(test), is dynamic sometimes the payload will come and sometimes it won't, and the payload name is temporary, may after some time it will become "abc" or anything.

In this case,
I want to Identify the "test" is a nested dict or not.
If it is nested dict I want to know the "key" of the nested dictionary, How can I solve this.

Answer (score 2):

iterate and check

```py
for key, value in outer_dict.items():
    if isinstance(value, dict):
        print(key)
```